# Difference between Initialization of ListView and TextView in Fragment onActivityCreated() function

Tags: android, listview, textview

When I initialize **ListView** inside **OnActivityCreated()** method of a class that extends Fragment as given below :

```
  ListView listView=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

then it works fine but when i do same thing for the **TextView** i.e initialize textView in same way inside the same method of class that extends Fragment

```
textView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

then my app crashes and log shows null pointer exception . I want to know the reason behind this behavior . !! Xml Code is Given Below :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="some tect"
    android:textSize="28sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you paste your xml code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong.
Just do

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ListView listView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

}

Initialize all view as above.

Comment: But ListView is not giving any error and working absolutely fine On the otherhand TextView causes Runtime Error. Why is that so ?

Comment: Is there  any Listview with same id in your Activity?!

Comment: no sir.. There is only one list view in my activity.

Comment: Activity or fragment be clear.. Your question is contradictory review once..
And getActivity().findViewbyId is not best practice..